Revit Link Names in APS
How can I get the RevitlinkedDocuments metadata (like link Name) using APS Viewer?
In AEC data I can found documentId and instanceId but do not know how to use that info to get link specific metadata, like link name, etc

You may have to compress the source design into a zip file, containtaining the Host rvt file and the relating linked files. When launching the Model Derivative translation job ensure you set the attribute: ‘compressedUrn: true’ as well specify the attribute:'rootFilename' to be file name of the Host Rvt file. Please refer to the documentation on how to set up your job: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/#body-structure

I am using Publish from within REVIT to upload to ACC. The links are embeded into the SVF.  No problem with geometry. The question is how to access each model name associated with each documentId, returned by linkedDocuments metadata
